# validate if there are multiple index on array javascript angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

so I have this array

```
array = [
{id:1,value:1},
{id:2,value:1},
{id:1,value:2},
{id:1,value:3},
{id:2,value:2},
{id:1,value:4},
{id:2,value:3}
]
```

I want to sort it out and make an output like this

```
array = [
{id:1,value:4},
{id:2,value:3}
]
```

I want to achive that using javascript, or is angularjs have the ability to do this ? thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi please see here http://jsbin.com/nozag/2/edit?html,js,output

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope){
 $scope.array = [
{id:1,value:1},
{id:2,value:1},
{id:1,value:2},
{id:1,value:3},
{id:2,value:2},
{id:1,value:4},
{id:2,value:3}
];
  $scope.uniq = [];

  for (var i=$scope.array.length-1; i>0; i--)
    {
     var arr = $scope.array[i];

      var contains = false;

      angular.forEach($scope.uniq, function(u){

        if (u.id==arr.id) 
          {
            contains = true;

          }


      });

      if(!contains){
         $scope.uniq.push(arr);

      }



    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to count the number of object with a certain id, how about [countBy](http://underscorejs.org/#countBy) defined in Underscore.js?

```
array = _.countBy(array, function(obj) { return obj.id; });
```

Comment: umm actually I want to achieve this using javascript only... thanks for your response though :)

Answer (score 0):

write a function for group by in java script

```
function groupBy( array , f )
{
  var groups = {};
  array.forEach( function( o )
  {
    var group = JSON.stringify( f(o) );
    groups[group] = groups[group] || [];
    groups[group].push( o );  
  });
  return Object.keys(groups).map( function( group )
  {
    return groups[group]; 
  })
}
```

and call it as

```
var result = groupBy(list, function(item)
{
  return [item.id];
});
```

which in your case will return the data as i.e the value of result will be

```
   [
    [
      Object { id=1, value=1},
      Object { id=1, value=2},
      Object { id=1, value=3}, 
      Object { id=1, value=4}
    ], 
    [
      Object { id=2, value=1},
      Object { id=2, value=2},
      Object { id=2, value=3}
    ]
  ]
```

Now write a function for summing up value with same id

```
function getData(groupByCategory)
{
  var  finalData=[];
    for(var i=0;i< groupByCategory.length;i++)
    {
    var temp=0;
        for(var j=0;j<groupByCategory[i].length;j++)
        {
            temp+=parseInt(groupByCategory[i][j].value);
        }
        finalData.push({"category":groupByCategory[i][0].id, "value":temp})
    }
   console.log(finalData);//final data is your required results
}
```

and call it as
getData(result);
The working fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LLbck/)

Although the function seems quite big . But it works. I am trying to find some alternate way. Will update it soon if get the same.

Comment: actually it returned with Object { category=1, value=10}, Object { category=2, value=6} like this .. I think it doesn't suit with the current array ?